# onclick submit can't call JavaScript function with setTimeout and document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, timeout

I am tring to call `timedText()` function when click on submit, and than call `setTimeout()` and replace tag `<p>` with 1 seconds, 2 seconds and 3 seconds.

```
<script>
    function timedText()
    { 
        var x=document.getElementById('txt1');

        var t1 = setTimeout(function(){x.innerHTML="1 seconds"},1000);
        var t2 = setTimeout(function(){x.innerHTML="2 seconds"},2000);
        var t3 = setTimeout(function(){x.innerHTML="3 seconds"},3000);

    }
</script>
<p>
    <a href="#">
        Izmeni<p id="txt1"></p>  
    </a>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="answer" value="Postavi" onclick="timedText()"/>
```

Comment: This is working: http://jsfiddle.net/RA5pw/

Comment: The problem is that when submit form I create tag <p id="txt1"></p> and onclick call function timedText().

Answer (score 0):

A few things changed:

- Changed submit button to a standard button.  Submit button probably reloading page, and never firing action.  Either way, not appropriate for a function call onclick.
- Changed onclick on the html button to be assigned by the javascript.  It's the modern way to do this, and more reliable.
- Cleaned up the html slightly.  The p tag was inside the anchor, which isn't ideal.  This is optional mostly though.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/q9Juv/

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <a href="#">Izmeni</a>
    <p id="txt1"></p>  
</p>
<input type="button" id="button" name="answer" value="Postavi" />
```

**JS**

```
 function timedText(){ 
     var x=document.getElementById('txt1');
     var t1=setTimeout(function(){x.innerHTML="1 seconds"},1000);
     var t2=setTimeout(function(){x.innerHTML="2 seconds"},2000);
     var t3=setTimeout(function(){x.innerHTML="3 seconds"},3000);
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',timedText);
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed, and why.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the submit button is submitting the page.

Personally, I like to use `<button onclick="dosomething()">Click me!</button>`. But some browsers treat that as a submit button too... so make sure you `return false;` in the event handler (ie. `onclick="dosomething(); return false;"`)

Comment: hint: add `type="button"`

Comment: -whines- I dun wanna! `<button type="button">` is stupid! Should be the default, really...

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps this will help you to see things in a clearer way (hopefully):**

```
<p><a href="#">Izmeni<p id="txt1"></p></a></p>
<input type="submit" name="answer" value="Postavi" onclick="StartTimer(3)"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var timerId = null;
    var element = document.getElementById("txt1");
    function StartTimer(numOfSeconds)
    {
        element.innerHTML = String(numOfSeconds)+" seconds";
        timerId = setInterval(TimerIsr,1000);
    }
    function StopTimer()
    {
        clearInterval(timerId);
        element.innerHTML = "";
    }
    function TimerIsr()
    {
        var numOfSeconds = Number(element.innerHTML.split(" ")[0]);
        if (numOfSeconds > 2)
            element.innerHTML = String(numOfSeconds-1)+" seconds";
        else if (numOfSeconds == 2)
            element.innerHTML = "1 second";
        else
            StopTimer();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This work when the line <p><a href="#">Izmeni<p id="txt1"></p></a></p> is created, but I create this line in the same when submit form.

Comment: And I don't no how to fix that